# cannot get value combogrid jquery eui from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I try create combogrid jquery eui. I follow the tutor but the value not show..

this my script combogrid..

```
<select id="nama_barang" class="easyui-combogrid" name="nama_barang" style="width:250px;"
                        data-options="
                        panelWidth:600,
                        value:'006',
                        idField:'id,
                        textField:'nama_barang',
                        url:'tiket/getBarang',
                        columns:[[
                        {field:'kode_barang',title:'Initial Barang',width:100},
                        {field:'nama_barang',title:'Nama Barang',width:300},
                        {field:'spesifikasi',title:'Spesifikasi',width:120},
                        {field:'merk',title:'Merk',width:100}
                        ]]
                        "></select>
```

and this is my function from my controller tiket.

```
public function getBarang() 
    { 
    $q = isset($_POST['q']) ? $_POST['q'] : '';  // the request parameter
    $rs = mysql_query("Select * from tb_barang where nama_barang like '$q%'");
    echo json_encode ($rs) ;    
    }
```

Thanks for your reply and attention..

Comment: `mysql_query`? Why not use the `active records` of `CI`? Consider uppgrading to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: And `$_POST['q']`... Why don't you use CI's (great) features for security and syntax...? However... YOU DON'T EVEN POST any `q` in the code submitted... AND - there is no javascript to handle the json returned... Post your entire relevant code please...

Comment: i just follow the tutor from this [link](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combogrid.php)

Comment: Read the FAQ. Don't post links here. Also we can never guess how you implemented that code. (+ the mysql security in the PHP code at that link is terrible. Use CI syntax and you will be fine...)

Comment: Read the FAQ before you ask a question,and would be better if you include your javascript code in your question